# Проект не видит фреймворк VLC, Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, framework, vlc

Скачал готовый фреймворк **MobileVLCKit** с сайта http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/ios/

Импортировал его в проект. Добавил **Bridging File**

```
#ifndef KartinaTV_Bridging_Header_h
#define KartinaTV_Bridging_Header_h
#import <MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h>

#endif /* KartinaTV_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Далее попробовал его использовать `import MobileVLCKit`.

Но выдает ошибку **No Such Module**

```
../Desktop/XCodeProjects/KartinaTV/KartinaTV/PlayerViewController.swift:4:8: No such module 'MobileVLCKit'
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35211/discussion-on-question-by-hadevscode-----vlc-swift).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением проблемы стало получение `TVVLCKit.framework` и использование в проекте без **import**